# make div show at a particular position no matter screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable div that contains a number of cards. I wish to fix it to a certain position from the left for screens > 1500px.

```css
.list-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-right: 10%
}

.card {
  height: 180px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: 40px
}


/* For fixing the width at 1500px, this is what I do: */

@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
  .list-wrapper {
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <div class="card" />
  <div class="card" />
  <div class="card" />
  <div class="card" />
  <div class="card" />
  <div class="card" />
</div>
```

The issue with this is that for larger screens, the list is clipped off before it reaches the end of the screen(since I fixed its width). I wish to make the list take the entire screen width and make sure the list doesn't move towards the left as screen size increases. How do I do this?

Comment: Your criteria aren't clear. Do you want the list to have a fixed width, or do you want it to start a certain distance from the left? You can't have both except in a fairly narrow range of circumstances. Either use more media queries or a flex row with two columns.

Comment: I want the list to start a certain distance distance from the left, and take up the remaining screen width

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make elements to scale at any screen size, consider using `vw` or `vh` instead of pixel